# Discrete logarithm/ solving Diffie Hellman?

Tags: discrete-logarithms

First, apologies. I'm decent at math, but i don't have a degree in it. Please excuse any ignorance on my part. And if any of my math is wrong, please correct me!

So, for anyone not familiar with the diffie-hellman problem it is:

> given the following:
>
> - g = can be any number (but usually 2, and known before hand)
> - p = an absurdly large, known prime
> - X = (g<sup>a</sup> % p)
> - Y = (g<sup>b</sup> % p)
>
> where only a and b are unknown, find K = (g^ab) % p

Using simple math, I notice that all of the following are equal:

- X<sup>Y</sup> % p
- (g<sup>a</sup> % p)<sup>g<sup>b</sup> % p</sup> % p
- (g<sup>abg</sup> % p)
- (g<sup>ab</sup> % p)<sup>g</sup> % p
- K<sup>g</sup> % p

As long as all that math is correct, and the knowledge that Diffie-Hellman is still unsolved, that means this is the furthest you can get. the real question:
when both g and p are known, what makes solving for K in (K<sup>g</sup> % p) so difficult?

Comment: I think that the jump from step 2 to 3 in your argument is not correct, are you saying that $(g^a)^{g^b}$ is the same as $g^{abg}$?

Comment: You're not going to like this answer, but it's just really hard.  You can plot things like $y=g^x \mod p$ for various fixed base and modulus and what you get looks like complete buckshot (correlation 0).   There's just no nice patterns like in real exponentials which give us nice logarithms.

Comment: In the ring $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ there is no exponentiation like $X^Y$. We have powers $x^n$ where $x$ is an element of the ring, but $n$ must be an ordinary integer. Well, if we assume that the base is $\neq0$, then, by Little Fermat, you can reduce the exponent modulo $p-1$. Anyway $X^Y$ is not well-defined, when $X$ and $Y$ are residue classes. My main point is that you cannot mix bases and exponents at all, and expect any usual rules of arithmetic to hold. Also, I don't think you follow even the usual rules, but I didn't even look closely.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are integer powers in Diffie-Hellman.   The OP didn't state this.